# When should we use Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Nuget package alone?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Couldn't understand the actual use case when should we use **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**

I am trying out efcore and created a sample application which does CRUD operations on the database. The packages I was required to make it work are

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools** - Provides tools to run migrations and stuff through package manager console

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** - Sql Server database provider

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** - Provides design time components.

And I am able to make the application work, and I get that the above packages reference **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**. (Though it is not in the dependencies under the project, we can see it by running `list package` command)

Apart from these packages referencing the **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore**, Is there any use case so that we can actually install this package and do stuff?

[image: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Nuget Package]

Comment: See it as an interface waiting for an implementation. Can you write "stuff" only with interfaces? Sure! But only when the interfaces have implementations things actually start to happen.

Comment: Does the "stuff" you referring to in this case represent the packages like providers, design, and tools packages?

Comment: It's just a metaphor. With just `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` you can create a full EF project with classes, relationships, mappings and all ("stuff"). But if try to actually use it, you'll get "No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. (...)", so you have to add the appropriate NuGet package and configuration to make it actually do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision with EF Core was to break things out into separate packages to make it easier to just include what you need. So for instance if you don't want lazy loading you don't have the overhead of .Proxies, same goes for if you don't want things like designers.

Situations where you might have a reference to EF Core without things like .SQLServer: Encapsulating your own helpers and such for working with EF. My default project structures often have a Domain.EF project for base functionality to work with EF's `IQueryable`. For my DbContext, Repository pattern, and base entity definitions to make "doing stuff" a bit easier and more consistent, as a result it doesn't need to access the full gambit that is EF Core.

The EF Core packages I install for the projects that actually "do stuff" are EntityFrameworkCore, .Relational & .Abstractions, and then the provider, whether .SqlServer or something like NpgSql for PostgreSQL. In some cases I will also add .Proxies if I want lazy loading but in most cases I don't enable it. I don't use designers so benefit from no overhead to support that.